# React - Dynamically Render Select Options

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to make the contents of the second (and all subsequent) dropdowns render based on the selection made in the first dropdown next to 'Category'.

All of the other dropdowns should render dynamically and allow a user to select multiple entries.

Currently, the options in the first dropdown render perfectly, the second dropdown renders fine, but none of the options in the `.map()` function in `createInputs()` will render.

https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-galois-cwlvw?fontsize=14

Comment: create a stackblitz or a codesandbox

Comment: ok im on it now

Comment: Your `createInputs ` is returning multiple <select>. I hope this is intentional.

Comment: The intention is to create one select input per element in an array that I am growing - will post the sandbox in a moment

Comment: Make an array for options in state e.g. [{id, label}...] and render out your options with that using array.map. When you need to change the options update the array in state.

Comment: With a complicated state like that you might be better off using a reducer and `useReducer`.

Comment: @DhananjaiPai added a sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-galois-cwlvw?fontsize=14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your map function for q.skills was missing a return. I've updated that portion of code:

```
      {somejobs &&
        somejobs.map((q, w) => {
          if (q.jobname == category) {
            console.log("Hello world");
            {
              return q.skills.map((x, y) => {  //Return was missing on this line
                console.log(JSON.stringify(x.skillname));
                console.log(JSON.stringify(q.jobname));
                return (
                  <option key={y} value={`${x}`}>
                    {x.skillname}  //You don't need to stringify this
                  </option>
                );
              });
            }
          }
        })}
```